# What happens when I add a Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, oop, build, build-process

When I add a dependency to the pom.xml file and build with "mvn package", what steps does Maven take with that dependency code?

Does it physically grab the java code from that dependency's package and put it into the JAR?  And why do I need to add the dependency at all ... why can't Maven just look at my import statements and fully qualified names and figure out which dependencies I need?

Comment: *why can't Maven just look at my import statements and fully qualified names and figure out all the dependencies I need* for example, you have a reference to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` from [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/), which version of jackson library should be used: 2.3.x, 2.4.x, 2.5.x? Saying *the latest version available* is not always an option due to compatibilities with other technology you use.

Comment: Additionally, fully qualified class names are not guaranteed to be universally unique — if you use a class name such as `com.great.project.SomeClass` it could be your own class or somebody else’s. And there could be several projects which happen to use this name. A class could be used in project A version 1.0 but then be removed and be absent in newer versions. And so on. It is not feasible in practice to find the right code based only on class name, even fully qualified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general in all `pom.xml` we found dependency like this -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Here `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` are 3 keys by which a jar is uniquely identified. These 3 combination works like a coordinate system for uniquely identifying a point in a space using x, y and z coordinates.

Whenever you issue a `mvn package` command `maven` tries to add the the jar file indicating by the dependency to you build path. For doing this maven follows these steps -

1. Maven search in your local repository (default is ~/.m2 for `linux`). If the dependency/jar is found here then it add the jar file to you build path. After that it uses required class file from the `jar` for compilation.
2. If the dependency is not found in ~/.m2 then it looks for your local private repository (If you already have configured any using `setting.xml` file) and maven central remote repository respectively. If you don't have any local private repository then it directly goes to the maven central remote repository.
3. Whenever the jar is found in the local/remote repository it is downloaded and saved in ~/.m2.

Going forward, when you again issue a `mvn package` command then it's never search for the dependency to any repository since it already in your `~/.m2`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have only the standard maven plugins from the default superpom, adding a dependency will:

- download the specified version to your local repository
- use it to compile
- use it to run tests

There are several maven plugins which can be used to include dependencies in a package. These include:

- maven-war-plugin
- maven-ear-plugin
- maven-assembly-plugin
- appassembler-maven-plugin

In addition, the maven-shade-plugin can be used to combine your dependencies into the jar file of your own code.

None of these are used unless you add them to your pom.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency will allow you to download 3rd party libraries using maven.

```
 <dependencies>
    <!--    Spring dependency -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

for example it will import spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar under your maven dependencies. After you update the project using maven. Then you will able to use this jar in your code.

> why can't Maven just look at my import statements and fully qualified
>   names and figure out which dependencies I need?

Because what if there are same method that were overloaded by two different jars? Maven won't able to determine which one to import. Good example would be hibernate and JPA annotations. They're alike but yet use different imports.

Answer (score 1):

Maven will download the new dependencie(s) to your local repository and then use this to compile your JAR.

If you are packaging your application as a web archive (WAR file), it would include the binaries of the dependency (and any binaries it depends on) in your WAR file.

Comment: Basically, it depends on the type of project you are building... If it's just a basic JAR, then it won't include any 3rd party libraries in your final JAR artefact. You can also do things like create a super-JAR (a JAR with all dependencies) with Maven than just a JAR

Answer (score 1):

1. `mvn package` takes whatever compiled code you have in the project and puts it in its distribution form. If your packaging format is `jar`, then maven will build your project's jar file as a result of the `mvn package` call.
2. Whether Maven grabs binaries outside of your project is dependent upon the packaging type.  The `jar` package type only packages code local to the project you're building from and doesn't grab binaries from outside projects, but other packaging methods may have different behaviors.
3. You need to define the dependency in the first place because Maven manages multiple versions of the same namespace. E.g., you could specify something like `import org.jfree.JFreeChart;`, but from this statement alone, Maven doesn't know if you want JFreeChart version 1.0.16 or 1.0.17, which is why you're required to specify it in the POM file.

Comment: Interesting, I looked at the .jar that was created and the dependency artifact it downloaded wasn't included anywhere.  How does Maven go from "download the dependency" to "packages only code local to the project"?  And why is it that some of my .jars are like 40+ MB if they are only holding local code?

Comment: It all depends on how you have your project set up. Short of seeing your POM file, I can't tell you why your jars are that big (do you have a resources folder with big files in it?).  As for the downloading question - maven downloads dependencies prior to the compile step, which is required for package to work if certain class files haven't been compiled yet, but this just downloads maven dependencies to your local maven repo.